# Keep upper n rows of a pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, filter

how would I delete all rows from a dataframe that come after a certain fulfilled condition? As an example I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as  pd
xEnd=1
yEnd=2
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'y':[1,2,3,3,4,3], 'id':[0,1,2,3,4,5]})
```

How would i get a dataframe that deletes the last 4 rows and keeps the upper 2 as in row 2 the condition `x=xEnd` and `y=yEnd` is fulfilled.
EDITED: should have mentioned that the dataframe is not necessarily ascending. Could also be descending and i still would like to get the upper ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not 100% sure i understand correctly, but you can filter your dataframe like this:

```
 df[(df.x <= xEnd) & (df.y <= yEnd)]
```

this yields the dataframe:

```
   id   x   y   
0   0   1   1   
1   1   1   2
```

If x and y are not strictly increasing and you want whats above the line that satisfy condition:

```
 df[df.index <= (df[(df.x == xEnd) & (df.y == yEnd)]).index.tolist()]
```

Comment: that works fine for the example, but it is not given that the upper rows are smaller than `xEnd` and `yEnd`. So i must somehow get the row index of the row that fulfills the condition

Comment: (assumes that xEnd yEnd is only satisfied in one row)

Comment: works fine thanks! yeah it should be only contained in one row

Comment: I get a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (30,) (0,)` from time to time. Do you know what it means? @Christian Sloper

Comment: presumably there is no row that satisfy yEnd.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123712/valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes-6-0-when

Comment: might interest you. I a got some weird error using your approach

Answer (score 3):

To slice your dataframe *until* the first time a condition across 2 series are satisfied, first calculate the required index and then slice via `iloc`.

You can calculate the index via `set_index`, `isin` and [`np.ndarray.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
idx = df.set_index(['x', 'y']).isin((xEnd, yEnd)).values.argmax()
res = df.iloc[:idx+1]

print(res)

   x  y  id
0  1  1   0
1  1  2   1
```

If you need better performance, see [Efficiently return the index of the first value satisfying condition in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020764/efficiently-return-the-index-of-the-first-value-satisfying-condition-in-array).

Comment: That works fine, thanks a lot! I made it to `idx+2`, to keep the row itself as well.

Comment: @Mauritius, That's strange: `idx+1` should do it (as in my example).

Comment: you are right of course! realized now when compiling. My first try did sth weird but yes `idx+1` is correct. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`df = df.iloc[[0:yEnd-1],[:]]`

Select just first two rows and keep all columns and put it in new dataframe.
Or you can use the same name of variable too.