# return next row of dataframe based on matching condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

Is this the most efficient way to get the next row of data based on a matching value in the prior row? It seems terribly cumbersome but the `Int64Index` type seems to not play well.

```
df_of_urls = {'ID': [100,101], 'URL': ['https://www.firsturl.com','https://www.secondurl.com']}
df_of_urls = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_of_urls)

prior_url = 'https://www.firsturl.com'

next_url = df_of_urls.iloc[df_of_urls[df_of_urls['URL']==prior_url ].index+1,1].values[0]
```

Comment: Depends, how many times are you performing this? You might consider `shift`, for example, to make a new column of values with each row offset by 1 index

Comment: I don't get the call to `list()` though

Comment: no; list was not needed. good call

Comment: Can you add a small example `df_of_urls` dataframe to your question? (or even better, a full code example)

Comment: I should have done in the first place. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing a series is more efficient than indexing a dataframe.

```
# Index using iat accessor
next_url = df_of_urls['URL'].iat[np.where(df_of_urls['URL']==prior_url)[0][0] + 1]

# Index using NumPy array
next_url = df_of_urls['URL'].values[np.where(df_of_urls['URL']==prior_url)[0][0] + 1]
```

This algorithm is inefficient for certain cases. A full iteration is always required, even when the condition is satisfied near the beginning of the array. A manual loop can solve this problem by terminating immediately when the condition is satisfied.

See also: [Efficiently return the index of the first value satisfying condition in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020764/efficiently-return-the-index-of-the-first-value-satisfying-condition-in-array).