# Pandas dataframe: Remove secondary upcoming same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
col1  col2
 a     0
 b     1
 c     1
 d     0
 c     1
 d     0
```

On `'col2'` I want to keep only the first `1` from the top and replace every `1` below the first one with a `0`, such that the output is:

```
col1  col2
 a     0
 b     1
 c     0
 d     0
 c     0
 d     0
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the index of the first `1` and set others to `0`:

```
mask = df['col2'].eq(1)
df.loc[mask & (df.index != mask.idxmax()), 'col2'] = 0
```

For better performance, see [Efficiently return the index of the first value satisfying condition in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020764/efficiently-return-the-index-of-the-first-value-satisfying-condition-in-array).

Comment: Can you think of a good solution for the case when the index is arbitrary, like `Index(['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']` AND col2 could be something like `[2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1]`?

Comment: @timgeb, To adapt this solution, I think you can use positional indexing (instead of index labels). Something like `df.loc[mask & (np.arange(df.shape[0]) != np.where(mask)[0][0]), 'col2'] = 0`. But I'm sure there are more Pythonic ways.

Comment: Ah, I thought of using numpy, too. Just a bit differently. See my case 3. ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Case 1**: `df` has only ones and zeros in col2 and integer indexes.

```
>>> df
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     1
3    d     0
4    c     1
5    d     0
```

You can use:

```
>>> df.loc[df['col2'].idxmax() + 1:, 'col2'] = 0
>>> df
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     0
3    d     0
4    c     0
5    d     0
```

---

**Case2**: `df` can have all kinds of values in col2 and has integer indexes.

```
>>> df # demo dataframe
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     2
3    d     2
4    c     3
5    d     3
```

You can use:

```
>>> df.loc[(df['col2'] == 1).idxmax() + 1:, 'col2'] = 0
>>> df
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     0
3    d     0
4    c     0
5    d     0
```

---

**Case 3**: `df` can have all kinds of values in col2 and has an arbitrary index.

```
>>> df
  col1  col2
u    a    -1
v    b     1
w    c     2
x    d     2
y    c     3
z    d     3
```

You can use:

```
>>> df['col2'].iloc[(df['col2'].values == 1).argmax() + 1:] = 0
>>> df
  col1  col2
u    a    -1
v    b     1
w    c     0
x    d     0
y    c     0
z    d     0
```

Answer (score 4):

#### `np.flatnonzero`

Because I thought we needed more answers

```
df.loc[df.index[np.flatnonzero(df.col2)[1:]], 'col2'] -= 1
df

  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     0
3    d     0
4    c     0
5    d     0
```

---

Same thing but a little more sneaky.

```
df.col2.values[np.flatnonzero(df.col2.values)[1:]] -= 1
df

  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     0
3    d     0
4    c     0
5    d     0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy` for an effficient solution:

```
a = df.col2.values
b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[a.argmax()] = 1
df.assign(col2=b)
```

```
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     0
3    d     0
4    c     0
5    d     0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `drop_duplicates` with `reindex`

```
df.col2=df.col2.drop_duplicates().reindex(df.index,fill_value=0)
df
Out[1078]: 
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     0
3    d     0
4    c     0
5    d     0
```

Answer (score 1):

i like this too

```
data['col2'][np.where(data['col2'] == 1)[0][0]+1:] = 0
```

Comment: Chained indexing is *not* recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Sooo many options, here's mine... almost the same as timgebs answer (found independently), but still different ;)

Find the index of col2 that has the first occurence of a 1, and change all row values after that index to 0:

```
df['col2'].iloc[df.col2.idxmax()+1:] = 0
```

Comment: Be careful, this sets *all* values to `0` after the specified index, not just the ones equal to `1`. Though that's the same with some other answers too.

Comment: Totally agree. Your solution is more general.

Answer (score 0):

```
id = list(df["col2"]).index(1)
df.iloc[id+1:]["col2"].replace(1,0,inplace=True)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Chained indexing is *not* recommended.