# Modifying the first line of a DataFrame subject to a condition

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

I have a dataframe that looks as follows

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"ID":[11,12,13,14,25],\
"Name":["Alice","Bob","Charlie", "Dan", "Erin"], "X":[1,0,0,0,0]})

   ID     Name  X
0  11    Alice  1
1  12      Bob  0
2  13  Charlie  0
3  14      Dan  0
4  25     Erin  0
```

I want to select the first row for which `X` is 0, and change the value to 1. I tried

```
df[df["X"]==0]["X"].iloc[0] = 1
```

But this doesn't seem to modify the dataframe `df` at all. This is odd to me since I do not get any error message, and since removing the `=1` yields

```
>>> df[df["X"]==0]["X"].iloc[0]
 0
```

as expected.

I suspect that the conditioning creates a copy of the dataframe, and so the dataframe `df` simply never gets modified.

What would be the best way of accomplishing this to get

```
   ID     Name  X
0  11    Alice  1
1  12      Bob  1
2  13  Charlie  0
3  14      Dan  0
4  25     Erin  0
```

Of course this needs to be done systematically since I will need to iterate the process.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will using `idxmax`

```
df.loc[df.X.eq(0).idxmax(),'X']=1
df
Out[153]: 
   ID     Name  X
0  11    Alice  1
1  12      Bob  1
2  13  Charlie  0
3  14      Dan  0
4  25     Erin  0
```

Comment: Very similar to what I was going to post: `df.loc[df['X'].ne(1).idxmax(), 'X'] = 1`

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) / [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas.DataFrame.iat) for scalar setting

The difficulty arises because you wish to mix *positional* row indexing with *label-based* column indexing. Choose one and stick with it for rows and columns.

You can use **labels** throughout, similar to [@Wen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53787481/9209546) but via `at`:

```
df.at[df['X'].eq(0).idxmax(), 'X'] = 1
```

Or you can **integer positional** indexing throughout via `iat`:

```
df.iat[df['X'].eq(0).values.argmax(), df.columns.get_loc('X')] = 1
```

Both solutions yield the same result. The former is likely more readable.

```
print(df)

   ID     Name  X
0  11    Alice  1
1  12      Bob  1
2  13  Charlie  0
3  14      Dan  0
4  25     Erin  0
```

[`pd.Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) / [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) are vectorised, but not particularly efficient. If efficiency is a concern, see [Efficiently return the index of the first value satisfying condition in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020764/efficiently-return-the-index-of-the-first-value-satisfying-condition-in-array).