# Change 1st row of a dataframe based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have 2 columns on whose value I want to update the third column for only  1 row.

I have-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,3,4,4],
                   'B':[2,2,4,3,2,1],
                   'C':[0] * 6})
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  0
1  1  2  0
2  2  4  0
3  3  3  0
4  4  2  0
5  4  1  0
```

If A= 1 and B=2 then only 1st row has C=1 like this -

```
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  1  2  0
2  2  4  0
3  3  3  0
4  4  2  0
5  4  1  0
```

Right now I have used

```
df.loc[(df['A']==1) & (df['B']==2)].iloc[[0]].loc['C'] = 1
```

but it doesn't change the dataframe.

Comment: my eyes.... please update your question without images

Comment: Why would you expect changes to be made to an entire dataframe when you restrict its scope by using `iloc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution if match always at least one row:

Create boolean mask and set to first `True` index value by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
mask = (df['A']==1) & (df['B']==2)

df.loc[mask.idxmax(), 'C'] = 1
```

But if no value matched `idxmax` return first `False` value, so added `if-else`:

```
mask = (df['A']==1) & (df['B']==2)

idx = mask.idxmax() if mask.any() else np.repeat(False, len(df))
df.loc[idx, 'C'] = 1
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  1  2  0
2  2  4  0
3  3  3  0
4  4  2  0
5  4  1  0
```

---

```
mask = (df['A']==10) & (df['B']==20)

idx = mask.idxmax() if mask.any() else np.repeat(False, len(df))
df.loc[idx, 'C'] = 1
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  0
1  1  2  0
2  2  4  0
3  3  3  0
4  4  2  0
5  4  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to ensure only the *first* matching criteria is satisfied:

```
mask = df['A'].eq(1) & df['B'].eq(2)
df.loc[mask & mask.cumsum().eq(1), 'C'] = 1

print(df)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  1  2  0
2  2  4  0
3  3  3  0
4  4  2  0
5  4  1  0
```

If performance is a concern, see [Efficiently return the index of the first value satisfying condition in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020764/efficiently-return-the-index-of-the-first-value-satisfying-condition-in-array).