# Pandas find idxmax() between range

Tags: python, pandas

I have this timeseries df:

```
                    Current
2018-09-01 00:00      -0.01
2018-09-01 00:01      -0.03
2018-09-01 00:02      -0.01
2018-09-01 00:03       0.03
2018-09-01 00:04      -0.02
2018-09-01 00:05      -0.04
2018-09-01 00:06       0.05
```

I am trying to find the first instance of a `Current` value being > 0.01. If I use

```
findValue = (df['Current'] > 0.01).idxmax()
```

I will return:

`2018-09-01 00:03       0.03`.

However, I would like to ignore the first 5 rows, so that the return should be

```
 2018-09-01 00:06       0.05
```

I have tried using shift():

```
findValue = (df['Current'] > 0.01).shift(5).idxmax()
```

But this doesn't seem right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) for seelct all columns without first `5` by indexing:

```
N = 5
findValue = (df['Current'].iloc[N:] > 0.01).idxmax()
print (findValue)
2018-09-01 00:06
```

Another idea is create another boolean mask by `np.arange` and length of DataFrame and chained by `&`:

```
m1 = df['Current'] > 0.01
m2 = np.arange(len(df)) >= 5
findValue = (m1 & m2).idxmax()
print (findValue)
2018-09-01 00:06
```

---

If need select by value in `DatetimeIndex`:

```
findValue = (df['Current'].loc['2018-09-01 00:05':] > 0.01).idxmax()
print (findValue)
2018-09-01 00:06:00

m1 = df['Current'] > 0.01
m2 = df.index >= '2018-09-01 00:05'
findValue = (m1 & m2).idxmax()
print (findValue)
2018-09-01 00:06:00
```

BUT:

`idxmax` return first `False` value, if not match any value:

```
m1 = df['Current'] > 5.01
m2 = np.arange(len(df)) >= 5
findValue = (m1 & m2).idxmax()

print (findValue)
2018-09-01 00:00:00
```

Possible solution is use `next` with `iter`:

```
m1 = df['Current'] > 5.01
m2 = np.arange(len(df)) >= 5
findValue = next(iter(df.index[m1 & m2]), 'no exist')

print (findValue)
no exist
```

If performance is important, check this nice @jpp Q/A - [Efficiently return the index of the first value satisfying condition in array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53020764/2901002).

Comment: Thanks. For the first solution, how can I get just the index of the 5th row (Start of the idxmax range: `2018-09-01 00:04`?)

Comment: @wazzahenry - use `df.index[4]`, because python count from `0`