# Filter Values in Python of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that I need to filter once a value has been exceeded but not after.  Here is an example of the dataframe:

```
    Dip    MD
0   70      5000
1   80      6000
2   90      7000
3   80      8000
```

I want to filter out everything before Dip goes above 85 the first time so the resultant array should look like this:

```
    Dip     MD
0   90      7000
1   80      8000
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [cummax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummax.html)

```
In [71]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Dip': [70, 80, 90, 80], 
    ...:     'MD': [5000, 6000, 7000, 8000]})         

In [72]: df[df.Dip.gt(85).cummax()]                   
Out[72]: 
   Dip    MD
2   90  7000
3   80  8000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the positional index of the first value satisfying a condition:

```
idx = next(iter(np.where(df['Dip'] > 85)[0]), df.shape[0])
```

Then slice your dataframe by integer position from this value onwards:

```
res = df.iloc[idx:]
```

Choosing `df.shape[0]` as the default if your condition is never satisfied ensures the entire dataframe is returned in this scenario.

**Performance note**

For larger data sets, you may find integer indexing more efficient than Boolean indexing:

```
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 100, 10**6)})

%timeit df[df['A'].gt(90).cummax()]                                   # 36.1 ms
%timeit df.iloc[next(iter(np.where(df['A'] > 90)[0]), df.shape[0]):]  # 4.04 ms
```

If efficiency is a primary concern, see [Efficiently return the index of the first value satisfying condition in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020764/efficiently-return-the-index-of-the-first-value-satisfying-condition-in-array). The idea is you don't have to traverse your entire series if the condition is satisfied earlier.