# Numpy: array of arrays, select the first value bigger than zero

Tags: python, numpy

My data looks like this:

```
all = [[-2,-1,0],[-1,-0.5,3],[-1,0.2,3],[0.2,1,3],[0.5,1,4]]
```

What I need to do is to select the first array which value in position [0] is bigger than zero and return me in this specific array the value of the element in position 1. I am a bit stuck, any idea? In my case it will be the array [0.2,1,3] , and in this array it should return me 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `next` with a generator expression, then use list indexing:

```
res = next(x for x in all_arr if x[0] > 0)[1]  # 1
```

Don't use `all` for a variable name, this is a built-in.

If you are interested in optimizing performance with a NumPy array, see [Efficiently return the index of the first value satisfying condition in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020764/efficiently-return-the-index-of-the-first-value-satisfying-condition-in-array).

Comment: I have the following error in my jupyter notebook: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable. The data were just an example..

Comment: @Viktor.w, Restart your session and *make sure you don't use any built-ins as variable names*. Use `all_` or `all_arr`, for example.

Comment: I was not precised enough in my explaination. In my original code, the array is of type numpy.ndarray

Comment: @Viktor.w, My code works with a NumPy array too (you can iterate an 2d array in the same way as a list of lists). The issue is something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional masking

```
all_arr = np.array([[-2,-1,0],[-1,-0.5,3],[-1,0.2,3],[0.2,1,3],[0.5,1,4]])
boolean = all_arr[:,0]>0
# [False False False  True  True]

print (all_arr[boolean][0,1]) # 0 because you just need the very first occurence
# 1.0
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Provide some feedback and let me improve the solution

Comment: This answer is fine for NumPy +1. With the disclaimer it will be fast for small arrays, slow for large arrays.

Comment: @jpp: The OP's queston starts with "Numpy:array of arrays" that's why I used a NumPy array