# Pandas search first row that match condition efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains few millions of rows. I want to select a value from a row based on a condition `C`.

I have the following code that is working :

```
all_matches= df.loc[C, "column_name"]
first_match = next(iter(all_matches), 'no match')
```

The problem is that it is extremely ineficient. I would like to know how is it possible to do something similar as `df.loc[C, "column_name"]`, but stoping at the first match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **always** there is first value use [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) for fast get first value:

```
df.loc[C, "column_name"].iat[0]
```

Or:

```
df.loc[C, "column_name"].values[0]
```

Another solution is change [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53020765/2901002):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_name':['a','b','va'],
                   'col':[1,2,3]})
from numba import njit

@njit
def get_first_val_nb(A, B, k):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] > k:
            return B[i]
    return 'no match'

A = df['col'].values
B = df['column_name'].values

idx = get_first_val_nb(A,B, 2)
print (idx)
va
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested and appears that `at` is faster than `iat`. The others are not suitable becaus they are either deprecated or they are vector grabbers.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 100))

%timeit df.iat[50,50]=50 # ✓
%timeit df.at[50,50]=50 #  ✔
%timeit df.set_value(50,50,50) # will deprecate
%timeit df.iloc[50,50]=50
%timeit df.loc[50,50]=50

7.06 µs ± 118 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
5.52 µs ± 64.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
3.68 µs ± 80.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
98.7 µs ± 1.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
109 µs ± 1.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```