# Find the first index of the DF between 2 (or more) value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Having a `df` with pandas, I want to have the first index occurrence of `"V1" | "V2"` if possible without having to scan all the DF. Can I make it stop at the first match ?

I started doing `i = df[(df["track"] == "V1")  | (df["track"] == "V2")].iloc[0]` but I got the full row and have a list.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want:

```
df.track.isin(['V1', 'V2']).idxmax()
```

---

If you want to stop on the first match here's one way using a generator comprehension:

```
match = {'V1', 'V2'}
next((ix for ix, i in enumerate(df.track.values) if i in match), None)
# 1
```

Comment: it scan all data ad failed if no match :(

Answer (score 2):

Use a bit changed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53020765) solution - for testing use `in` operator - it loop only to matching like your requirement:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def get_first_index_nb(A, k):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] in k:
            return i
    return None

#pandas 0.24+
idx = get_first_index_nb(df.track.to_numpy(), ['V1', 'V2'])
#oldier pandas versions
#idx = get_first_index_nb(df.track.values, ['V1', 'V2'])
print (idx)
```

Solution with [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) if possible no values matching with `if-else` statement and [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html), but it test all matching values:

```
m = df.track.isin(['V1', 'V2'])
idx = m.idxmax() if m.any() else None
```

Or:

```
idx = next(iter(df.index[df.track.isin(['V1', 'V2'])]), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html) or [`Series.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.index.html)

```
df[df.track.isin(['V1', 'V2'])].index[0]
```

or using [`callable`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable)

```
df.track.loc[lambda x: x.isin(['V1', 'V2'])].index[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `where` and `first_valid_index` to handle case when `V1` and `V2` not found. In that case, `first_valid_index` returns `None`

```
idx = df.where(df.track.isin(['V1', 'V2'])).first_valid_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use your same code but with below changes.

From this

```
i = df[(df["track"] == "V1")  | (df["track"] == "V2")].iloc[0]
```

to

```
df[(df["track"] == "V1")  | (df["track"] == "V2")].head(1).iloc[0]
```

Comment: this return a row

Comment: change it to .iloc[0] :)

Comment: Edited, You can use it now. :)

Comment: it returns a Serie

Comment: df[(df["track"] == "V1")  | (df["track"] == "V2")].head(1).index

Comment: it returns `RangeIndex`

Comment: If you don't want a range index, Use as below.

df[(df["track"] == "V1") | (df["track"] == "V2")].head(1).index.tolist()[0]

Since it is only one index, otherwise you can limit it as you like and get all your results stored in a list.